# Why are Cucumber and Capybara called that?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, bdd, acceptance-testing

Does anybody know why these names were selected for Capybara and Cucumber?
Or were they just picked randomly?

Comment: Cucumber and Capybara, in this context, are tools used by Ruby programmers.  For that reason, the off-topic reason "... [is] about general computing and hardware" does not reply.  It's something of a trivia question--nobody will ever need to know the answer to use either of these tools--but it should be left open, especially since its answer is based on fact + pretty solid conjecture--no opinion needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cucumber was written by Aslak Hellesøy and named by his fiancee.](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Cucumber-tool-for-BDD-named-as-such) He asked her for a "catchy, non-geeky sounding name" to replace its provisional name, "Stories".

The name Capybara appears to be a play on "webrat", the name of [a similar library](https://github.com/brynary/webrat) which predated Capybara. (An actual capybara is a large rodent native to South America, not really a "rat" but related.)